# Python: Split pandas dataframe by range of values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a simple dataframe in which I am trying to split into multiple groups based on whether the x column value falls within a range.

e.g. if I have:

```
print(df1)
  x
0 5
1 7.5
2 10
3 12.5
4 15
```

And wish to create a new dataframe, df2, of values of x which are within the range 7-13 (7 < x < 13)

```
print(df1)
  x   
0 5
4 15

print(df2)
  x
1 7.5
2 10
3 12.5
```

I have been able to split the dataframe based on a single value boolean e.g. ( x < 11), using the following - but have unable to develop this into a *range* of values.

```
thresh = 11
df2 = df1[df1['x'] < thresh]

print(df2)
  x
0 5
1 7.5
2 10
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a boolean mask for the range (7 < x < 13) by AND condition of (x > 7) and (x < 13).  Then create `df2` with this boolean mask. The remaining entries left in `df1` being the negation of this boolean mask:

```
thresh_low = 7
thresh_high = 13
mask = (df1['x'] > thresh_low) & (df1['x'] < thresh_high)

df2 = df1[mask]
df1 = df1[~mask]
```

Result:

```
print(df2)

      x
1   7.5
2  10.0
3  12.5


print(df1)

      x
0   5.0
4  15.0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `between` to categorize whether the condition is met and then groupby to split based on your condition. Here I'll store the results in a `dict`

```
d = dict(tuple(df1.groupby(df1['x'].between(7, 13, inclusive=False))))

d[True]
#      x
#1   7.5
#2  10.0
#3  12.5

d[False]
#      x
#0   5.0
#4  15.0
```

---

Or with only two possible splits you can manually define the Boolean Series and then split based on it.

```
m = df1['x'].between(7, 13, inclusive=False)

df_in = df1[m]
df_out = df1[~m]
```